# closed form representation of A132270

Tags: sequences-and-series

is there a closed form representation of oeis sequence A132270(https://oeis.org/A132270)?

for example, oeis sequence A004526(https://oeis.org/A004526) can be represented in closed form by

(1/4)*(-3 - (-1)^n + 2 n)=a(n)

Answer (score 1):

> "A132270      Floor((n^7-1)/(7*n^6)), which is the same as integers repeated 7 times. "
>   (...) "Also, floor[(n^7-n^6)/(7n^6-6n^5)] will produce this sequence as well."

It's right there on the page
$$a_n = \left\lfloor \frac{n^7 - 1}{7n^6} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n^7 - n^6}{7n^6 - 6n^5} \right\rfloor$$

Comment: i thought floor was not closed form?

Comment: @jbreezy What would make floor not closed-form?

Comment: Maybe you should ask if there is a general form _without_ floor function, or (in a new question), if the floor function of a rational function can be represented by elementary functions excluding $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor, \lceil\cdot\rceil$ and $[\cdot]$.

Comment: Ok, can the sequence i described in my post above be represented without the floor function?